# Web Essentials Why it is unable

Tags: web-essentials

I am working on Visual Studio 2013 with Web Essentials installed.  I try to create CSS bundle files in LESS, but Web Essentials is unable (as the image below).  I just tried to update Web Essentials by installing Web Essentials 2013.5, I got a message saying "The version is already installed."
[image]

Please direct me how to get Web Essentials enable.
Thanks

Comment: you must select the folder where the file css